# when i tried to run my app after adding INTENT in MAINACTIVTY it show this error

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: The error is in Image.cLick here for Screenshot]

How I can solve this error help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score -1):

seems like `btnDish` is null. Are you assigning it a value somewhere in code above?

You should be doing something like

```kotlin
btnDish = findViewById(R.id.btnDish)
btnDish.setOnClickListner { 
   //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: yes but I set INTENT on OnClickListner

Comment: what should I do here? I just want to open the next activity by clicking button

Comment: no, i am not assigning it a value, I just declared it and set OnCLickListnere on btnDish just to open the next Activity

Comment: You need to assign `btnDish` the actual value before using it, thats line 1 of my code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

```
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  
  public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
     }
  });
```

Comment: Please add some description of your suggestion.

Comment: error occurred because you are using btn.findViewById(); replace "." with "=" i.e btn=findViewById(R.id.btnid);

Comment: Hi developer, please edit the question and add your answer there. It's pretty common only to share the code, but it's important to provide a description if you want to get positive results.